# Creating scene from .dae throws EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: ios, 3d, ios8, collada, scenekit

Using the code automatically generated by Xcode when you create a game application, I have managed to substitute the .dae used by new ones that work, but when I use a more complex one the app crashes and throws a EXC_BREAKPOINT(), any idea of the reason and how to fix it? (the file that doesn't open is 4,1MB big and the others that open are all 450KB, 750Kb or something like that).

This is the gigantic crash log (didn't take anything off):

```
Incident Identifier: 5E8A97C9-8B0D-4182-92D3-32A845F0D9F5
Hardware Model:      iPad4,1
Process:             mediaserverd [29]
Path:                /usr/sbin/mediaserverd
Identifier:          mediaserverd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-10-20 14:23:47.371 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D167)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000187fce85c
Triggered by Thread:  15

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c764 __CFRunLoopRun + 932
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   mediaserverd                    0x000000010008ed8c 0x10008c000 + 11660
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194e57a9c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194e3d998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.coremedia.playerserver
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001897af2a0 figMovieServerThread + 428
6   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coremedia.playerserver.notifications
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001897af4c0 figNotificationThread + 124
6   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.coremedia.cmsession
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885fd29c cmsmHALPropertyListenerResponseThread + 160
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   BTAudioHALPlugIn                0x00000001001b13cc 0x10019c000 + 86988
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreAudio                       0x0000000187c1ac1c HALRunLoop::OwnThread(void*) + 184
5   CoreAudio                       0x0000000187c257bc CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 100
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   VirtualAudio                    0x00000001009db8f0 0x1009d8000 + 14576
6   VirtualAudio                    0x00000001009db814 0x1009d8000 + 14356
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.coremedia.remakerserver
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   MediaToolbox                    0x0000000189920508 figRemakerFamilyServerThread + 336
6   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.coremedia.recorderserver
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   Celestial                       0x000000018c7028c8 figRecorderServerThread + 804
6   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coremedia.imagequeue.coreanimation
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001897edc14 piqca_PollingThread + 704
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.coremedia.imagequeue.coreanimation
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001897edc14 piqca_PollingThread + 704
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 12 name:  com.apple.coremedia.virtualDisplayJobProcessor
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   MediaToolbox                    0x000000018981aae4 fjpRunScheduler + 472
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   mediaserverd                    0x0000000100092364 0x10008c000 + 25444
5   mediaserverd                    0x00000001000967e8 0x10008c000 + 42984
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   CoreMotion                      0x0000000188666538 0x188628000 + 255288
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 15 name:  com.apple.coremedia.recorder.worker
Thread 15 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187fce85c __CFBasicHashDeallocate + 24
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187fcdfe4 __CFBasicHashDrain + 284
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ea9a38 CFRelease + 312
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187fcdfe4 __CFBasicHashDrain + 284
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ea9a38 CFRelease + 312
5   CoreMedia                       0x000000018859dd90 sBufFinalize + 84
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ea9a38 CFRelease + 312
7   Celestial                       0x000000018c734fd4 figrecorder_serviceStillImageQueue + 8200
8   Celestial                       0x000000018c72a954 figrecorder_workerThread + 11284
9   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 16 name:  com.apple.coremedia.recorder.preview
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   Celestial                       0x000000018c72ac50 figrecorder_previewThread + 640
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 17 name:  com.apple.coremedia.livesource.splitter
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   Celestial                       0x000000018c712318 livesource_splitterThread + 9268
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 18 name:  com.apple.coremedia.livesource.preview
Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   Celestial                       0x000000018c7123c4 livesource_previewThread + 152
6   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 19 name:  com.apple.coremedia.livesource.worker
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   Celestial                       0x000000018c7131b4 livesource_workerThread + 3508
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 20 name:  H6ISPServicesThread
Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   H6ISP.mediacapture              0x000000018b86d29c H6ISP::H6ISPServicesThreadStart(H6ISP::H6ISPServicesThreadParams*) + 152
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 21 name:  com.apple.coremedia.samplebufferprocessor.autofocus
Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52394 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594c84 WaitOnCondition + 12
2   CoreMedia                       0x0000000188594bc4 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 156
3   MediaToolbox                    0x00000001897ee854 activitySchedulerOnThread + 28
4   CoreMedia                       0x00000001885c0b9c figThreadMain + 252
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 22 name:  H6ISPFrameReceiverRealTimeThread
Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6e570 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f6c700 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187ead6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187f02d54 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   H6ISP.mediacapture              0x000000018b869d80 H6ISP::H6ISPFrameReceiverRTThreadStart(H6ISP::H6ISPFrameReceiverThreadParams*) + 536
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f52e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194f39cf4 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194e43018 _dispatch_worker_thread + 156
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3e18 _pthread_body + 164
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd3d70 _pthread_start + 136
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194fd1550 thread_start + 0

Thread 15 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001276da060   x1: 0x0000000100401280   x2: 0x00000001276da068   x3: 0x0000000000000055
    x4: 0x00000001000c8180   x5: 0x0000000000000004   x6: 0x00000001280abe00   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0040180080200c03   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000000012  x11: 0x00000001952a8200
   x12: 0x0000000127764000  x13: 0x0000000024dc28fc  x14: 0x0000000047bceb96  x15: 0x00000000287f8512
   x16: 0x0000000194fcd054  x17: 0x00dd1f3d6684946c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001276da060
   x20: 0x00000001276da068  x21: 0xffffffffffffffff  x22: 0x0000000100001280  x23: 0x0000000000000012
   x24: 0x00000001952a6200  x25: 0x00000001952aa000  x26: 0xffffffff00000000  x27: 0x00000000a7baadb1
   x28: 0x00000000a5baadb9  fp: 0x0000000102cea940   lr: 0x0000000187ea9a3c
    sp: 0x0000000102cea8f0   pc: 0x0000000187fce85c cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: does not seem to be a SceneKit bug: Thread 15 name:  com.apple.coremedia.recorder.worker

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem so. Because the same code does work for other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

==>  OS Version:          **iOS 7.1** (11D167)

I thought SceneKit is supported only starting with iOS8 or later?

Comment: Makes sense, but just updated to iOS8 and got the same error =/

Comment: Is the DAE file you are using a valid one?  Can you see the model in  XCode when you click on it in the Navigator?  Can you post sample code?

Comment: So, in your viewDidLoad, all you do is load the scene and nothing else? Just by replacing the default model with your more complex model - it crashes?  If you post your code, maybe we can help figure it out.